# Mirror Calendar between two SharePoint sites

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar, sharepoint-designer

I have two SharePoint sites and want to mirror their calendars.
Lets say site 1 Calendar is editable, then any change made to its Calendar should reflect on site 2's Calendar.

I will really appreciate if some one knows how to do it or even have an idea coz I am totally lost. Also, I am using SharePoint 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Clarification: these are two different SharePoint sites (not pages).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. But, it is not exactly as you want. Here, you can add an overlay of a calendar in which the main calendar will be treated as master calendar and the other calendars will be treated as children. 
If you add an item/task in the children calendar, the item/task will be automatically added to the master calendar. Here is the procedure....

1. Go to your Calendar that you want to make as a master calendar.
2. Click on “Calendars Overlay” in the calendar tab.
3. Click new calendar and yo will have a form to fill up.
4. Enter the Web url for the Site that contain your child calendar
5. This overlay is specific to a given view, so you may want to specify the view in your calendar that you want to roll -up.

Note : Please note that the limit of calendars in an overlay is 10

Comment: Thanks for the help! It gives me an "unexpected error" when I try to do this. As I said before, this needs to be done between two different SharePoint sites.

Comment: Would you please try again? This works between two different SharePoint Sites.